How to install a local LAN Plesk server with OAuth2 integration with AzureAD
In our school we teach basic webdesign and programming primarily for WordPress and vanilla html/css/JavaScript. We currently are looking into installing a server in-house that does not necessarily needs to be accessible from wan (that might change though).
We look at Plesk as that is our outside world solution and we want to familiarise our students with that same interface. Our current wan solution suffers from frequent low performance as for cost reasons it is a shared hosting.
Apart from a good server and enough network capacity what do need to consider when setting up a local in house server?

This is really broad. There are loads of guides online with resource planning instructions for specific servers. A question that may be a better fit here would be "We have begun implementing X server in our LAN and we're experiencing Y problems. We've researched Z and Q, and tried P and L, with M result, but we really need to reach B. How do we do that?". Your question requires consulting, which this site does not really do.
